# How to retrieve identity value from AngularJS POST request

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have the following method in my Web API

```
public IHttpActionResult PostNewOrder(myClass.Order ord1)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
      return BadRequest(ModelState);
  }
  using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
  {

      ctx.Orders.Add(ord1);
      ctx.SaveChanges();

      return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = ord1.OrderID }, ord1);

  }
}
```

I call the API from AngularJS as follows:

```
function CreateOrder(url, inData) {
        $http.post(url, inData)
       .success(function (data, status, header) {
           $scope.result = data;
           console.log("Order ID is " + $scope.result.OrderID);
       })
       .error(function (data, status, header) {
           $scope.result = "Data: " + data +
               "<hr />status: " + status;
           console.log(header.responseText);
       });
    }
```

The above logs the correct Order ID, but how can i retrieve that ID from outside the function? After function call?

```
CreateOrder('http://server/AppName/api/PostNewOrder', ord1);
```

using `return $scope.result.OrderID` inside the function does not work

I also tried calling the function as follows:

```
$scope.NewOrderID =CreateOrder('http://server/AppName/api/PostNewOrder', ord1);
```

while adding return to my function

```
function CreateOrder(url, inData) {
        $http.post(url, inData)
       .success(function (data, status, header) {
           $scope.result = data;
           console.log("Order ID is " + $scope.result.OrderID);
           return $scope.result.OrderID;
       })
       .error(function (data, status, header) {
           $scope.result = "Data: " + data +
               "<hr />status: " + status;
           console.log(header.responseText);
       });
    }
```

but `$scope.NewOrderID` comes up undefined

Comment: Have you tried setting a variable that is defined outside your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .then instead of .success and return a promise.  Else if you still want to go with .success, use deferred API and return the promise anyway.  Then in the calling code, use .then.

> a service

```
        app.service('OrderService', function ($http, $q) {

            return {
              CreateOrder: CreateOrder
            };

            function CreateOrder(url, inData) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get(url, inData)
               .success(function (data, status, header) {

               deferred.resolve({
                 OrderID:  data.id
               });


               })
               .error(function (data, status, header) {
               deferred.reject(msg);
               });

               return deferred.promise;

            }
        });
```

> in controller
>        OrderService.CreateOrder('order.json', null).then(function(id){
>           console.log(id);
>       });

Refer to [this](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http) and [this](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/) on how to make this decision.  But the general verdict is not to use .success if inside a service, but to go for .then.  Again it is up to you.  It is just that .success is implemented by AngularJS that way.

[My Working plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/uCx1PiliTDPT3hYh5YXI?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/uCx1PiliTDPT3hYh5YXI?p=preview):